# What is Dynamic system update

Tags: lineageos, partitions, ab-partition

Is seamless update(a/b partition) same as dynamic system update

Or

Can I use DSU in A only devices & how do I know if my device supports dsu updates.

I have lineageos 18.1

Comment: It's very well documented officially. See https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/dynamic-system-updates and https://developer.android.com/topic/dsu. Further explanation: https://www.xda-developers.com/android-q-dynamic-system-updates-project-treble